# Cannot find the driver in the classpath.

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is what I'm working with right now. I can't seem to figure out why when I run it I'm still getting this error. I don't know what to do.

Error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find the driver in the classpath!"

Please help me. I don't know what to do anymore.

```html
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author Taylor Dean
 */
public class CustomerUtil {
    private static Connection connection;
    
        private CustomerUtil() {}

       public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
              
          try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("loaded!");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
}
          
           
           if (connection != null) {
            return connection;
        }
        else {
            try {
                // set the db url, username, and password
                
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mma";
                String username = "root";
                String password = "21334966154Dahk";

                // get and return connection
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        url, username, password);
                return connection;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
            }            
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw e;
            } finally {
                connection = null;                
            }
        }
    } 
    
    
}
```

Comment: How did you install the library? If it can't find the driver, you're probably missing a few steps adding it to the "CLASSPATH". It's the list of all the place to look to load your libraries. For example, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html

Comment: As Sean noted, you must both download the driver and tell your application how to find it. The exact steps may vary by your development environment/tools; which IDE (if any) are you using? You may also which to consider Gradle or Maven to assist in dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MySQL JDBC driver to the classpath.

First, download the JDBC driver from the MySQL web site -- the JDBC "connector". This is a `.jar` file that you will place in a known directory. For example, I got `mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar` in a directory.

Then, when starting the application, add this JAR file to the classpath, as in:

```
java -cp my_dir/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar CustomerUtil
```